# Typeahead + MySQL + JSON

Tags: mysql, json, typeahead

I am fighting for hours with Typeahead (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).
I successfully try examples from here : http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

But, when i try to add it to my code, i have issues with MySQL & JSON.

Here my code :

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" size="75">
```

JS

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/ajax/altimit.ajax.php?autocompleteTag=1',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: 'term=' + query,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          process(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Ajax

```
if (isset($_POST['autocompleteTag'])) {
    $tag = autocompleteTag($tag);
    echo $tag;
}
```

PHP

```
function autocompleteTag($tag) {
    $sql = doSQL("SELECT nom FROM tags WHERE nom LIKE '%".$tag."%'");
    while ($tab = tabSQL($sql)) {
        $resultat[] = array('label' => $tab['nom']);
    }
    return json_encode($resultat);
}
```

It seems that my JS do not retrieve ajax data, and i don't know why...

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: you are passing `$tag` ... what is the value sent with this variable?

Comment: This is an array : [{"label":"test1"},{"label":"test3"},{"label":"test4"},{"label":"test5"},{"label":"test6"},{"label":"test"}]